# Make item slide back to 0 with Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to get my element to go back to where it came from.
Drag stores how far it has travelled, so I thought I could tell it to go back towards 0 1 pixel at time.
This does not work however (it is triggered by a touchend). When I look in the dev tools I see the {{drag}} value is correct, but the if statement is not triggered.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function bounceToZero() {
    if({{drag}} != 0) {
        document.querySelector('pull-to-action').drag = {{drag}} - 1;
        if({{drag}} != 0) {
            setTimeout('bounceToZero()',1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
Here is the full element

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-icon/core-icon.html">
<polymer-element attributes="action distance container color" name="pull-to-action">
  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: calc(100% - 8px);
      text-align:center;
      z-index:99;
    }
    .refreshIcon {
      background-color:white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid {{color}};
      padding: 8px;
      top: calc(({{drag}}px - 50px) / 3);
      color: {{color}};
      opacity: calc({{drag}} / {{distance}});
      transform: rotate({{drag}}deg);
      filter: grayscale({{desat}}%);
      -webkit-filter: grayscale({{desat}}%);
    }
    </style>
        <span flex><core-icon class="refreshIcon" icon="icons:refresh"></core-icon></span>
        <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var dragObs = 0;
            var lastTouchY = 0;
            var startTouchY = 0;
            var endTouchY = 0;
            var desat = 100;
            var touchstartHandler = function(e) {
                if (e.touches.length != 1) return;
                lastTouchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
                startTouchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
                document.querySelector('pull-to-action').width = window.innerWidth;
            }
            var touchmoveHandler = function(e) {
                var touchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
                var touchYDelta = touchY - lastTouchY;
                lastTouchY = touchY;
                endTouchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
                if (document.getElementById('{{container}}').scrollTop == 0) {
                    dragObs = endTouchY - startTouchY;
                    desat = 100 - ((dragObs / {{distance}}) * 100);
                    document.querySelector('pull-to-action').desat = desat;
                    document.querySelector('pull-to-action').drag = endTouchY - startTouchY;
                }
                if (document.getElementById('{{container}}').scrollTop == 0 && touchYDelta > 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
                if (document.getElementById('{{container}}').scrollTop == 0 &&dragObs > 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
            } 
            var touchendHandler = function(e) {
                if (document.getElementById('{{container}}').scrollTop == 0 && endTouchY - startTouchY >= {{distance}}) {
                    {{action}};
                    document.querySelector('pull-to-action').drag = {{distance}};
                    dragObs = {{distance}}
                    setTimeout('bounceToZero()',2000);
                } else {
                    function bounceToZero() {
                        if({{drag}} != 0) {
                            document.querySelector('pull-to-action').drag = {{drag}} - 1;
                            if({{drag}} != 0) {
                                setTimeout('bounceToZero()',1000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstartHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmoveHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener('touchend', touchendHandler, false);
        });
        </script>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            action: 'alert("You need to set the action attribute")',
            distance: '100',
            container: 'body',
            drag: '0',
            desat: '100',
            color: '#ccc'
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I managed to get it working, here's what I did.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-icon/core-icon.html">
<polymer-element attributes="action distance container color" name="pull-to-action">
  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: calc(100% - 8px);
      text-align:center;
      z-index:99;
    }
    .refreshIcon {
      background-color:white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid {{color}};
      padding: 8px;
      top: calc(({{drag}}px - 50px) / 3);
      color: {{color}};
      opacity: calc({{drag}} / {{distance}});
      transform: rotate({{drag}}deg);
      filter: grayscale({{desat}}%);
      -webkit-filter: grayscale({{desat}}%);
    }
    </style>
        <span flex><core-icon class="refreshIcon" icon="icons:refresh"></core-icon></span>
        <script>
        var dragObs = 0;
        function bounceToDistance() {
            if (dragObs > 150) {
                dragObs = dragObs - 3;
                setTimeout('document.querySelector("pull-to-action").drag = dragObs; bounceToDistance();',1);          
            }   
        }
        function bounceToZero() {
            if (dragObs > 0) {
                dragObs--;
                setTimeout('document.querySelector("pull-to-action").drag = dragObs; bounceToZero();',5);          
            }   
        }
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var lastTouchY = 0;
            var startTouchY = 0;
            var endTouchY = 0;
            var desat = 100;
            var touchstartHandler = function(e) {
                if (e.touches.length != 1) return;
                lastTouchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
                startTouchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
                document.querySelector('pull-to-action').width = window.innerWidth;
            }
            var touchmoveHandler = function(e) {
                var touchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
                var touchYDelta = touchY - lastTouchY;
                lastTouchY = touchY;
                endTouchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
                if (document.getElementById('{{container}}').scrollTop == 0) {
                    dragObs = endTouchY - startTouchY;
                    desat = 100 - ((dragObs / {{distance}}) * 100);
                    document.querySelector('pull-to-action').desat = desat;
                    document.querySelector('pull-to-action').drag = endTouchY - startTouchY;
                }
                if (document.getElementById('{{container}}').scrollTop == 0 && touchYDelta > 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
                if (document.getElementById('{{container}}').scrollTop == 0 &&dragObs > 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
            } 
            var touchendHandler = function(e) {
                if (document.getElementById('{{container}}').scrollTop == 0 && endTouchY - startTouchY >= {{distance}}) {
                    {{action}};
                    bounceToDistance();
                    setTimeout('bounceToZero();', 2000);
                } else {
                    bounceToZero();
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstartHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmoveHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener('touchend', touchendHandler, false);
        });
        </script>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            action: 'alert("You need to set the action attribute")',
            distance: '100',
            container: 'body',
            drag: '0',
            desat: '100',
            color: '#ccc'
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not use template inside script

```
function bounceToZero() {
  if(drag != 0) {
      document.querySelector('pull-to-action').drag = drag - 1;
      if(drag != 0) {
          setTimeout('bounceToZero()',1000);
      }
  }
}
```

add `this` context to drag if you need to

Comment: That didn't help :-/
The script is inside the template and the numbers are being passed through.

Thanks though

Comment: I have added my element to the first post.